# reledmac: \footnoteX within \edtext

Tags: footnotes, eledmac, reledmac, ledmac

I have a problem with footnotes within the edtext of the reledmac package. The footnoteA in the edtext{ quidem} is fine as is.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % vorher scrlayer-scrpage 
\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\date{}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
\newcommand{\textjuni}[1]{{\fontspec{Junicode}#1}}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\title{Incipit ordo sive breviarium} \maketitle 
\pstart \myparagraph{IN ADVENTU DOMINI}
\edtext{(9r)}{\Afootnote{(1r) SVE; }}
Ad vesperas  AN \textit{Benedictus}.
Nam quod\edtext{ quidem\footnoteA{corr., a.c.: 'quidam'}}{\Afootnote{- SVE;}} 
in illo spatio.
```

However, the output shows another footnote in the second footnote apparatus with a different counting number. Either no number or the same as in the actual footnote would be ok for me.

[image]

Does anybody of you have any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it is clearly a bug of reledmac. plese open a github issue.

Comment: issue opened https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/554

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is clearly a (r)(e)ledmac bug, but it has been quickly fixed.

I have send the new version (2.14.1) on the CTAN 4th of July morning.

Just wait until it will be available using tlmgr.

If you need it quickly, please download https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/master.zip, run pdflatex on the .ins file to get the new .sty file, and put these file along your project. That will suppress the calling of familiar footnote inside critical footnote.

Comment: you'r welcome. Note that you should do `quod \edtext{quidem` and not `quod\edtext{ quidem`